How should a coroutine accept a const range?
I want to implement a coroutine that accepts a range and keeps it intact (modules const reference).
Let coroutine_foo be a coroutine: How would you implement its signature?
Since it is expensive to copy a container and also coroutines must only accept references of objects that are guaranteed to be alive throughout the lifetime of the coroutine I think an inclusive foo_coroutine:

Accept ranges that are lvalues - in this case it should create a const lvalue reference which is safe, as the container is alive throughout the duration of the coroutine. I'm thinking of
foo_coroutine(const std::ranges::range auto&)
Accept range views by value. I'm thinking foo_coroutine(std::ranges::borrowed_range auto) accepting by value
for this as borrowed_range semantically guarantee cheap copy and it is safer to copy.
Should not accept containers by value (as these are expensive
to copy) - therefore it should block rvalue ranges. I'm thinking of: coroutine_foo(const std::ranges::range auto&&) = delete

To summarise, I want to allow these call signatures to coexist:
auto coroutine_foo(const std::ranges::range auto& rng) { 
   return coroutine_foo_impl(rng); 
}
        
auto coroutine_foo(std::ranges::borrowed_range auto rng) {
   return coroutine_foo_impl(std::move(rng)); // though move is probably pointless here
} 
    
auto coroutine_foo(const std::ranges::range auto&&) = delete;

They clearly cannot coexist as-is since the first and third are by reference and the second by value. How can I make them coexist?
Note: I think this would be the proper API for a coroutine that is given a range that should not be modified - but am I missing something?

This is what I came up with:
template<std::ranges::range R> 
auto foo_coroutine(R&& rng) {
    if constexpr (std::is_lvalue_reference_v<R>)
        return foo_coroutine_impl(std::ranges::subrange{rng}, std::move(func));
    else if constexpr (std::ranges::borrowed_range<R>)
        return foo_coroutine_impl(std::move(rng), std::move(func));
    //Deduction fails for rvalue non borrowed ranges

}

auto foo_coroutine_impl(const std::ranges::borrowed_range auto rng) {
   /*...*/ 
}


How about always pass the view by value and constrain it via constant_range?
#include <ranges>

template<std::ranges::view V>
  requires std::ranges::constant_range<R>
auto foo_coroutine_impl(V rng) {
   /*...*/ 
}

template<std::ranges::input_range R>
  requires std::ranges::viewable_range<R>
auto foo_coroutine(R&& rng) {
  foo_coroutine_impl(std::views::as_const(std::forward<R>(rng)));
}


That's a good point! I know not every view is a borrowed_range. However is every borrowed_range a view?

I asked it as a question, but then realized owner_view is not borrowed_range
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/79236820/not-every-view-is-a-borrowed-range-but-is-every-borrowed-range-a-view/79236829#79236829
Still not sure if there are others...
